# CSS system alternative to Masonry

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-masonry

I remember a CSS grid system alternative to Masonry (Vanilla) http://masonry.desandro.com/ . That site was black background and displaying/arranging colored boxes (periodic table elements) . It also had filtering boxes based on their shapes and size (like round, square e.t.c) . It was also using hardware acceleration. I spend a lot of time to find it but no luck. Anyone knows this site?

Comment: Please use a proper search engine and the tools designed for searching websites.

Comment: Here I'm not asking you guys to find me a random website/code. I'm asking the name of the CSS system which is a direct alternative to Masonry and it already exists, I just fotgot it's name. I'm not even asking "if there is such system". So I believe my question is legit.

Comment: I got value out of this question, since I was looking for Isotope. The qeustion could be better, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check the source of its counterpart, Isotope:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

Comment: Didn't even know it's the same guy

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this. And it works great with Bootstrap. Basically instead of container, I am using WALL:

```
<style>
.wall {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
} 
.wall > .brick {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:860px) {
    .wall {-moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; column-count: 2;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    .wall {-moz-column-count: 3; -webkit-column-count: 3; column-count: 3;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1700px) {
    .wall {-moz-column-count: 4; -webkit-column-count: 4; column-count: 4;}
}

</style>
```

This is designed so bricks must be a minimum of 400px. You can do math and change the `min-width`s if you don't like 400.

Comment: Tnx, but what about in IE 9

Answer (score 2):

I'd try Salvattore, it uses CSS for the configuration and all the design, no need to even touch JavaScript.

http://salvattore.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative if anyone finds it useful: http://suprb.com/apps/nested/