# Floating DIV's without vertical space

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to fix vertical space when floating DIV's with diffrent heights?

example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=2" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=6" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=7" /></div>
    <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=8" /></div>
</div>
<style>
    .container { width: 312px; }
    .floatingGrid { float: left; margin: 2px; }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ModuLIZER/gk1cjn1t/

In my case I don't care about the order just that element 5 and 6 is position directly under 1 and 2 without the space.

I should add this grid is responsive and I need to support IE9.

Comment: use css columns: http://jsfiddle.net/gk1cjn1t/6/ here are a lot of post about this topic, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779512/css-system-alternative-to-masonry

Comment: Fair enough, it's not very responsive though but I guess I can fix that with some media query breaks.

Comment: Ahh no IE9 support, that is a must. 
[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem creating floating columns and putting inside divs, this will simulate the grid layout i suppose you are looking for.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='column'>
       <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1" /></div>
       <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4" /></div>
       <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=7" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=2" /></div>
      <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5" /></div>
      <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=8" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
       <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3" /></div>
       <div class="floatingGrid"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=6" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .container { width: 312px; }
    .column { width:104px; float:left;  }
    .floatingGrid { }
</style>
```

Alternatively, if you cant create columns, there are some javascript libraries can do it like for example http://masonry.desandro.com/.

Comment: My bad... I should have added that it should support responsive design, so adding a div class='column' every third element is not a option as the grid can be a two column layout too.

Comment: Hmm if there is no elegant CSS solution i guess a js library is the way to go...
[isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html), [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [nested](http://suprb.com/apps/nested/) looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `float` and use `inline-block`what you are looking for is a masonry layout.

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huAxS/311/)

Comment: Don't know who downvoted but column-count is not a option for me as I must support IE9

Comment: If I may ask, what are you using this column grid for? If it is for example to showcase a gallery thumbnails or portfolio, I can recommend a plugin http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ , i have been using it fr a while(IE8+) well this is unless you need a pure css solution and no-filtering options. Good luck

Comment: Yes, it is a gallery grid... I think a js lib is the solution too, like [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html), [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [nested](http://suprb.com/apps/nested/)... whould have liked a clean CSS solution but IE9 is a b**tch ;) ... thanks